# SQL LEFT JOIN value NOT in either join column

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, join, left-join

I suspect this is a rather common scenario and may show my ineptitude as a DB developer, but here goes anyway ...

I have two tables: **Profiles** and **HiddenProfiles** and the **HiddenProfiles** table has two relevant foreign keys: *profile_id* and *hidden_profile_id* that store *id*s from the **Profiles** table.

As you can imagine, a user can **hide** another user (wherein his profile ID would be the *profile_id* in the **HiddenProfiles** table) or he can be **hidden** by another user (wherein his profile ID would be put in the *hidden_profile_id* column). Again, a pretty common scenario.

**Desired Outcome:**
I want to do a join (or to be honest, whatever would be the most efficient query) on the Profiles and HiddenProfiles table to find all the profiles that a given profile is both not hiding AND not hidden from.

In my head I thought it would be pretty straightforward, but the iterations I came up with kept seeming to miss one half of the problem. Finally, I ended up with something that looks like this:

```
SELECT "profiles".* FROM "profiles"
LEFT JOIN hidden_profiles hp1 on hp1.profile_id = profiles.id and (hp1.hidden_profile_id = 1)
LEFT JOIN hidden_profiles hp2 on hp2.hidden_profile_id = profiles.id and (hp2.profile_id = 1)
WHERE (hp1.hidden_profile_id is null) AND (hp2.profile_id is null)
```

Don't get me wrong, this "works" but in my heart of hearts I feel like there should be a better way. If in fact there is not, I'm more than happy to accept that answer from someone with more wisdom than myself on the matter. :)

And for what it's worth these are two RoR models sitting on a Postgres DB, so solutions tailored to those constraints are appreciated.

---

Models are as such:

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
    ...
    has_many :hidden_profiles, dependent: :delete_all

    scope :not_hidden_to_me, -> (profile) { joins("LEFT JOIN hidden_profiles hp1 on hp1.profile_id = profiles.id and (hp1.hidden_profile_id = #{profile.id})").where("hp1.hidden_profile_id is null") }
    scope :not_hidden_by_me, -> (profile) { joins("LEFT JOIN hidden_profiles hp2 on hp2.hidden_profile_id = profiles.id and (hp2.profile_id = #{profile.id})").where("hp2.profile_id is null") }
    scope :not_hidden, -> (profile) { self.not_hidden_to_me(profile).not_hidden_by_me(profile) }
    ...
end

class HiddenProfile < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :profile
    belongs_to :hidden_profile, class_name: "Profile"
end
```

So to get the profiles I want I'm doing the following:

```
Profile.not_hidden(given_profile)
```

And again, maybe this is fine, but if there's a better way I'll happily take it.

Comment: Can you show the models, so we can see the associations?

Comment: Sure, you just want to see the "has_many/belongs_to" bits? ... though I think they're pretty straightforward.

Comment: @Mischa, thanks for the edit! Couldn't quickly figure out how to make it look like that. ;-)

Comment: Yes. Just the names of the models and the associations should be enough. Then you could probably use an active record query, which is in my opinion a bit cleaner in a rails project.

Comment: Updated as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get this list just for a single profile, I would implement an instance method to perform effectively the same query in ActiveRecord. The only modification I made is to perform a single join onto a union of subqueries and to apply the conditions on the subqueries. This should reduce the columns that need to be loaded into memory, and hopefully be faster (you'd need to benchmark against your data to be sure):

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  def visible_profiles
    Profile.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN (
      SELECT profile_id p_id FROM hidden_profiles WHERE hidden_profile_id = #{id}
      UNION ALL
      SELECT hidden_profile_id p_id FROM hidden_profiles WHERE profile_id = #{id}
    ) hp ON hp.p_id = profiles.id").where("hp.p_id IS NULL")
  end
end
```

Since this method returns an ActiveRecord scope, you can chain additional conditions if desired:

```
Profile.find(1).visible_profiles.where("created_at > ?", Time.new(2015,1,1)).order(:name)
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I think you hit the nail on the head! I ran EXPLAIN on it and it does seem more performant! I'll give it another hour or so for other ideas then come back and mark this as answered. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Personally I've never liked the join = null approach.  I find it counter intuitive.   You're asking for a join, and then limiting the results to records that don't match.

I'd approach it more as

```
SELECT id FROM profiles p
WHERE 
NOT EXISTS 
 (SELECT * FROM hidden_profiles hp1 
  WHERE hp1.hidden_profile_id = 1 and hp1.profile_id = p.profile_id)
AND
  NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM hidden_profiles hp2 
  WHERE hp2.hidden_profile_id = p.profile_id and hp2.profile_id = 1)
```

But you're going to need to run it some EXPLAINs with realistic volumes to be sure of which works best.